# Understanding pthread_detach

Tags: c, pthreads

The following prints

```
In Main()
Hello World
Hello World
```

Why does this print Hello World twice? If I use pthread_join() the desired output occurs (only one Hello World preceeded by a In Main().

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s;
    void *res;
    pthread_t t1;

    s = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread_func, "Hello World\n");

    if (s != 0)
        printf("Err\n");

    printf("In Main()\n");

    s = pthread_detach(t1);

    if (s != 0)
        printf("Err\n");

    return 0;
}

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    char *s = (char *)arg;
    printf("%s", s);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I understand pthread_detach tells the library to release all of the resources utilized by the pthread once the thread is terminated... and since I terminate it at the end of thread_func, everything should be okay right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Minor point: `char *s = (char *)arg;` should be `char *s = arg;`

Comment: Also, this prints "Hello World" either 0, 1 or 2 times for me. Remeber, threads are not required to wait for each other unless specified explicitly, what you're experiencing here is called unspecified behavior (not the undefined one) and it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. With `pthread_detach` I only see one copy of the "Hello World" message. I tried adding a call to `sleep(3)` in the main thread to be absolutely sure that the thread had an opportunity to finish running, and I still only see the message once.

Comment: @ H2CO3. I'm not sure how to follow this then. Like you, I get either 0, 1, or 2 Hello World's as well. But, to me, it doesn't make sense logically yet (i'm new to pthreads). You say the behavior is unspecified, but if you think about it logically, the thread terminates execution once thread_func ends.

Comment: So, how does it ever print 2 times? I never call thread_func more than once (when the thread is first created), right?

Comment: According to the man page, "Attempting to detach an already detached thread results In unspecified behavior." Could this be what is occurring?

Comment: Are you redirecting output to a file ?

Comment: @cnicutar No, the code I posted is my entre code. I actually have it out of a book, except the pthread_detach is replaced with a pthread_join, and thread_func returns (void *)strlen(s). After reading about pthread_detach, I figured that calling pthread_detach and manually exiting the thread would be identical to calling pthread_join().

Comment: And I'm not piping it on the terminal. I am compiling with icc threading.c -o hello -lpthread, and typing hello to execute.

Comment: Can you try (just for fun) calling `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` call ?

Comment: Hmm.. I did that and now I am getting the correct answer a LOT more often. I am sometimes still getting 2 Hello Worlds, but previously it was almost every time. Now it is roughly one in five.

Comment: @JohnReddock: You're not including the header for `printf`. Oh, and how are you compiling/linking?

Comment: Could it be `printf` calls aren't locked on your platform ?

Comment: I see the same effect on gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1, even if I add `#include <stdio.h>` and compile with the `-pthread` option (`gcc -pthread -o test test.c`).  I can't explain why the second `Hello World` sometimes shows up.

Comment: One propably should better call `pthread_detach()` from the thread isself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you are using a non-thread-safe version of the standard library (prints, fflush...). I have already seen this kind of (apparently) non-logical behavior on a old unix-like real time system. There were two different versions of std library, one for single-threaded mode and one for multithreaded. Of course, the default was single threaded...
In general, accesses to file pointers and similar things should be serialized with mutexes. In your program there are two thread terminations, each may want to call implicitly an fflush, but since the underlying buffers are not meant to be accessed concurrently, it may happen that both flushes write the same data to the output file descriptor.