# creating 1 thread which outputs "new thread" any number of times

Tags: c, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding pthread_detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319793/understanding-pthread-detach)

The following code is creating a single thread which prints "new thread" .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
void *thr_fn(void *arg)
{
      printf("New thread\n");
      sleep(5);
      return (void *)1;
}
int main()
{
       pthread_t pid;
       void *t;
       pthread_create(&pid,NULL,thr_fn,NULL);
       printf("main thread\n");
       exit(0);
}
```

The output can be any of these:

```
    1.main thread 
      New thread
    2.main thread
    3.main thread
      New thread
      New thread
```

First and second are convincing . But can anybody explain the reason behind the third optional output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319793/understanding-pthread-detach - similar question asked yesterday

Comment: First off, the output could be any number of other things, since `printf` is not synchronised. Second, your program has undefined behaviour since you never join the thread.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : joining the threads remove the race condition in this program. How can it tell the reason of printing 2 "new thread".

Comment: @user1815906: Isn't it enough that "anything could happen"? "Anything" should cover "printing something twice"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure, that your program does not create two threads ;-)

Most likely you see the effects of a race-condition on `stdout` between your new thread and the main thread.  `exit` flushes and closes all streams. This might happen non-atomically and in parallel to the other thread writing into the same stream buffer and flushing that also to the file descriptor.

Comment: I know about the race condition but still I'm not able to understand why there are 2 "new thread". As both the threads have same file descriptor, don't they should print 1 "main thread" or 1 "new thread". May you please explain it with some example.

Comment: @user1815906: It's not the file descriptor which is important here. A file descriptor is just an ID given by the kernel to the program. but `printf` and everything working with `FILE *` does not operate on the file handle directly. Instead they are working with some buffer which is managed by the application. And if two threads work on the same buffer (one by doing `printf` the other by doing `fflush` inside the `exit`) at the same time... then all bets are open.